# Styles missing in IFrame (Asp.Net page)

Tags: css, iframe

I have an Iframe that initialy doesn't apply the CSS (checked the view source and the CSS link is available) but when I click on a button (submit) it reloads the same page with correct CSS and I can see the styles.

Any intial thoughts on why it is behaving like this?

Language: ASPX.Net

Comment: Could you please post a code example or even better, a link to a live example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling it in an iframe? Sometimes iframes (if on the same domain) can apply the styles within. Depends on how it's called. Also perhaps your headers are not set properly before you do a form submit. Do you have a URL we can see?